# functions from a module stating that they are not defined

Tags: python, function, module

so I have two .py files and I am trying to load the functions from the database_modules.py file into main.py however when I try to run the program, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'create_table' is not defined
```

the main.py file is in the main directory whilst database_modules.py is in a subdirectory (modules/database_modules.py)

main.py:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
from modules import database_modules

connection = sqlite3.connect('accounts.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

create_table()
data_entry(input('Please input your name:  '), hash(input('Please input your password:  ')))
read_entry()
quit()
```

database_modules.py:

```
def create_table():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accountDetails(name TEXT, password TEXT, dateCreation TEXT, accountID INT)")

def data_entry(name, password):
    dateCreation = (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    accountID = 1
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO accountDetails (name, password, dateCreation, accountID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
(name, password, dateCreation, accountID))
    connection.commit()

def read_entry():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accountDetails")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)

def quit():
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

thanks in advance as I am unsure how to gain the functions, the file worked fine until I attempted to turn my code into modules.

Comment: You have to use `database_modules.create_table`

Answer (score 0):

As was commented you need to specify which function you wish to use from the imported script: `database_modules.create_table`. Alternatively you can directly import all the functions in your database_modules file using `from modules.database_modules import *`. After which you can use them by name only like you've done. Or just import the one you need `from modules.database_modules import create_table`.